# How to costomize notifiction on android

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, push-notification

I'm building a React native app and I can send/receive notification from firebase or php api using this:

```
$msg = array
(
    'message'   => 'here is a message. message',
    'title'     => 'This is a title. title',
    'subtitle'  => 'This is a subtitle. subtitle',
    'tickerText'    => 'Ticker text here...Ticker text here...Ticker text here',
    'vibrate'   => 1,
    'sound'     => 1,
    'largeIcon' => 'large_icon',
    'smallIcon' => 'small_icon'
);
```

How can I costomize or displaying this notification like that:
[image]

Is this a simple image sent from server ?

Comment: You can achieve similar functionality by sending the image from the server along with an icon, title and message (small and long)

Comment: so the whole notification its simply an image that's it ?